# Rails instance variable created with FactoryGirl not defined in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

I have a view that displays either a welcome message or a video, depending on whether `@video` is defined. I am trying to write some tests for the view, but I can't seem to figure out how to cover the case where `@video` is defined.

Here is the view:

```
<div class="container" id="contents">
  <% unless defined? @video %>
    <div class="hero-unit">
      <h1>
        Khan-O-Tron<br />
        <small>Khan Academy has a lot of great videos. So many, in fact, that choosing just one is kind of annoying. Click the button below and let us choose one for you!</small>
      </h1><br />
      <a class="btn btn-large btn-success" href="/random">Get Started By Watching A Tutorial</a>
    </div>
  <% else %>
    <div class="hero-unit">
      <h1><%= @video.title %><br /> <small><%= @video.description %></small></h1>
      <br />
      <%= raw @video.get_embed_code %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Here are my tests:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "[Static Pages]" do
  describe "GET /" do
    before { visit root_path }
    subject { page }

    describe "#hero-unit" do
      describe "with @video not defined" do
        it "should have an H1 tag with the text 'Khan-O-Tron'." do
          should have_selector ".hero-unit h1", text: "Khan-O-Tron"
        end
        it "should have an H1 small tag with a description of our product." do
          should have_selector ".hero-unit h1 small", text: "Khan Academy has a lot of great videos. So many, in fact, that choosing just one is kind of annoying. Click the button below and let us choose one for you!"
        end
        it "should have a link to /random with the text 'Get Started By Watching A Tutorial'" do
          should have_link "Get Started By Watching A Tutorial", href: "/random"
        end
      end
      describe "with @video defined" do

        before { @video = FactoryGirl.create(:video) }

        it "should have an H1 tag with the video's title" do
          should have_selector ".hero-unit h1", text: @video.title
        end
        it "should have an H1 small tag with the video's description" do
          should have_selector ".hero-unit h1 small", text: @video.description
        end
        it "should have the video embedded in the page" do
          should have_selector "iframe"
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Why isn't the `@video` variable that I define using `FactoryGirl` being passed to the view?

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're doing the `visit root_path` before you've defined `@video`. Add `get root_path` right after the `@video = ....` line in the `before` block and it should work.

By the way, the correct way to go about this is using the rspec helper:

Add this right above the first `before` block:

```
let(:video) { FactoryGirl.create(:video) }
```

then in your second `before` block where you set the instance variable, replace the line with:

`assign(:video, video)`

and finally in your examples, replace `@video` with `video`.

More info [here](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs).

Comment: I am getting a new error now: `NoMethodError: undefined method `assigns' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1::Nested_1::Nested_2:0x007ff6706511e8>`. According to the `rspec-rails` readme, the proper usage is `assign(key, val)` instead of `assigns(key, val)`. I've tried both and get the same error message.

Comment: You're using Capybara? I've added the solution in the beginning of my question. Doesn't that solve your problem?

Comment: No, I'm still having the same issue.

Comment: I've tried the way you recommended as well. For some reason, it seems that `rspec/rails/view_assigns` isn't being required. That's the only possiblity I can think of since the error message I'm getting says that `assign` is not defined.

Comment: What version of rails, rspec-rails are you using?

Comment: Using rspec-rails (2.13.0)

Comment: Have you tried adding a `visit root_path` right after you set the instance variable?

Comment: I tried that's too, but nothing came of it. I decided to take a different route altogether, but I'm still having trouble. I'll probably make a new topic when I get off of work tonight. Thanks for your help!